# Could not perform EF Core for .NET Core Class Lib Project and .NET Core Web Api Project. Error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I split out my solution into multiple projects / layers. The technology which I am using is C# in .NET Core and Entity Framework Core.

I have Infrastructure project which is a .NET Core class library project which I put the DataContext class. If I put my connection string in the `DataContext` class directly, it works. I can perform the EF migration when I `set as startup project` of my Web Api project .

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    const string connectionString = "Server=STEVENGAI\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=CinemaDbNETCore;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        AppConfiguration appconfig = new AppConfiguration();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(appconfig.ConnectionString);
    }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

But, I need to put the connectionstring at appsettings.json instead. So, I installed these packages

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

and have this class which read the connectionstring from appsettings.json.

```
namespace CinemaApp.NETCore.Infrastructure
{
public class AppConfiguration
{
    public readonly string _connectionString = string.Empty;
    public AppConfiguration()
    {
        var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json");
        configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile(path, false);

        var root = configurationBuilder.Build();
        _connectionString = root.GetSection("ConnectionString").GetSection("CinemaDb").Value;
        //var appSetting = root.GetSection("ApplicationSettings");
    }
    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get => _connectionString;
    }

}
}
```

Then, I create another .NET Core console project to test if I could get the connection string which it did successfully. I can perform the EF migration when I `Set as Startup Project` of this Console Test project.

```
namespace ConsoleTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppConfiguration appconfig = new AppConfiguration();
        Console.WriteLine(appconfig.ConnectionString);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
}
```

But, the problem is when I switch back `Set as Startup Project` to Web Api project, and perform EF migration, it gives me this error `Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')`

I have copied the same connectringstring for both appsettings.json in Console Test project and Web Api project.

Comment: Can you show your Startup.ConfigureServices? where do you register DataContext ?

Comment: No. I don't have Startup.ConfigureServices because I am using .NET Core Class Library project, not .NET Core Web Application project

Comment: What value are you getting on `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`?

Comment: @viveknuna thanks for the pointer. I found out the issue already. In my web api project appsettings.json, I have `"ConnectionStrings"` but it actually detect connectionstring without "s", `"ConnectionString"`

Answer (score 0):

@viveknuna thanks for the pointer. I found out the issue already. In my web api project appsettings.json, I have `"ConnectionStrings"` but it actually detect connectionstring without "s", `"ConnectionString"`